# Select all rows (700000) very long time - hours

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I use mysql mariadb(Server version: 10.3.20-MariaDB-1:10.3.20+maria~stretch mariadb.org binary distribution).

I have ~700 000 records with columns:

- id
- **html (mediumtext) with very big average length in field: ~150000**
- date
- +2 small other

In html I have very long text (it's html's).
Now I need `select * from table;`, to analyse this html but this query takes over ~0.03819s per query (I tested on smaller part) so: total rows 700000*0.03819s per query = (700000*0.03819s)/60/60 = **over 7 hours of selecting!**

I have 8 cores and 60GB of RAM. Profiling query shows that time of transferring data is very very long.
How to speed it up? It's is possible, or that much of data it's too much for mysql and I need mongodb?

```
query_cache_limit = 64M 
query_cache_size = 1024M 
max_allowed_packet = 64M
net_buffer_length = 16384
max_connect_errors = 1000
thread_concurrency = 32
concurrent_insert = 2
read_rnd_buffer_size = 8M
bulk_insert_buffer_size = 8M
query_cache_limit = 64M
query_cache_size = 1024M
query_cache_type = 1
query_prealloc_size = 262144
query_alloc_block_size = 65536
transaction_alloc_block_size = 8192
transaction_prealloc_size = 4096
max_write_lock_count = 16
innodb_buffer_pool_size=30G
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2
innodb_thread_concurrency=16
innodb_flush_method=O_DIRECT
innodb_read_io_threads = 64
innodb_write_io_threads = 16
innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 20
```

```
MariaDB [db]> explain select id, href, html from raw limit 10;
+------+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+-------+
| id   | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra |
+------+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+-------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | raw   | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 658793 |       |
+------+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+-------+
1 row in set (0.227 sec)
```

after playing with indexes:

```
MariaDB [db]> show index from raw;
+-------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+-------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| raw   |          0 | PRIMARY  |            1 | id          | A         |      658793 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| raw   |          1 | id       |            1 | id          | A         |      658793 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| raw   |          1 | href     |            1 | href        | A         |      658793 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| raw   |          1 | date     |            1 | date        | A         |      131758 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
+-------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
4 rows in set (3.724 sec)
```

Comment: Hi, very interesting, perhaps try [`explain select`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/using-explain.html)

Comment: That's approximately 100GB of data. That's quite a lot. If you have slow storage devices, or if there are other high-impact processes running on the server and causing high load or competing for access to the storage, it could take a long time. I'd check the system load and swapping using [top](https://www.binarytides.com/linux-top-command/), and check for high I/O wait time with [iotop or iostat](https://www.2daygeek.com/check-monitor-disk-io-in-linux-using-iotop-iostat-command/).

Comment: Why are you running `select * from table` 700,000 times? Can you explain what you are actually trying to achieve? (Perhaps "it" can be achieved in a far more efficient manner, but we need to know what "it" is.)

Comment: This question is better suited to the dba forum

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  Do you have HDD or SSD disk drives?  Which Engine are you using?

Comment: Is that 38ms _per row_?

Answer (score 0):

38ms to fetch 150Kb from a spinning disk is quite fast.

query_cache_size = 1024M -- This is much too high.  Stop at about 50M.

A `PRIMARY KEY` is a unique index.  So, if `id` is the primary key, do not also say `KEY(id)`.

> It's is possible, or that much of data it's too much for mysql and I need mongodb?

Assuming you are running at disk speed, you cannot expect any other product to run faster.

What will the client do with 100GB of data in one batch?  MySQL will be happy to deliver it, but the client will probably choke to death.